# Cargar nueva pagina y script despues

Tags: javascript

Quería saber cómo se podría cargar una página web y después de ser cargada que se ejecute un script. He intentado de esta manera pero no hay manera.

En la consola y en la barra de URL:

```
javascript:window.open("http://www.google.es"); setTimeout(function(){alert("codigo");},2000);
```

Comment: eso parece inyección de código Js en una pagina ajena. No creo que sea facil...

Comment: La página que se abre, ¿tienes control sobre ella o es externa (como en el ejemplo de la pregunta)?

Comment: Aparte, ¿dónde quieres que se ejecute el script en la página nueva o en la que la abre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te refieres a que el contenido del sitio carge dentro de tu página?

si es así el método window.open() no te sirve (abre en una nueva ventana)

para cargar un sitio dentro de tu página y que este lanze un script, se puede lograr usando iframe

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("myframe").addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert("cargo sitio");
  });
</script>
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://musicaq.me"></iframe>
```

si estás intentando inyectar código a un sitio ajeno al tuyo es imposible por un tema de seguridad https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 3):

La mejor forma de hacer esto en páginas de tu proyecto es utilizar jQuery y el método `ready`. Este es el ejemplo más básico:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //aquí el código que deseas ejecutar
});
```

Si lo que quieres es abrir una nueva ventana y ejecutar una función JavaScript al abrirla y esta página es del mismo dominio de tu proyecto actual, puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
var ventana = window.open("http://midominio/nuevaUrl");
ventana.setTimeout(() => alert("codigo"),2000);
```

Cualquier intento de abrir una página fuera de tu dominio y agregarle funcionalidad no está permitido por ser cross-domain (a menos que le agregues el header respectivo de CORS y el sitio lo permita).

Comment: Iba a responder lo mismo, pero leyendo bien, la pagina que quiere cargar no es propia... es google.com y lo quiere hacer desde la barra de direcciones

Comment: Para que esto funcione OP necesita tener control sobre la página abierta. Además el código a ejecutar se ejecutaría siempre, incluso si la página no se abriese con un enlace como el indicado en la pregunta

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro respuesta actualizada.

Comment: He conseguido que funcione, Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

También existe otra manera, pero no es automática...
Y es por medio de "herramientas para desarrolladores" de Chrome o sus similares...
Para eso debes abrir manualmente la página y al presionar "Ctrl+Mayús+I" o F12 en Google Chrome e ir a la pestaña "console" y ahí puedes pegar tu Script, lo que sea que haga el Script solo funcionara para ti cada vez que hagas esos pasos (no creo que se pueda hacer automático).......

Pero creo que eso es lo que necesitas(o necesitabas), yo también estoy haciendo algo similar...
Hay una cierta página que no permite ni "import", ni "iframe" como decían anteriormente por las cuestiones de seguridad, pero al ejecutar el script en su página ya cargada puedo insertar el código que quiero y modificar su apariencia.... insertar algunos "iframe"s  que es lo que más necesitaba y como lo hago en una de las páginas de su dominio puedo utilizar libremente los "iframe".

Me gusta cómo me está quedando, en caso de que quieran ver la página y el Script avísenme.